# cmake build command produces empty output

Tags: windows, cmake

initial conditions:

simple source file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    printf("Hello, World!\n")
    return 0;
}
```

please pay the attention on missing ";" , that's for the testing.

also simple cmakelists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(test3 C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)

add_executable(test3 main.c)
```

the environment has been initialized so:

> C:\dev\workspace\test3\cmake-build-debug>"C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build\"vcvarsall.bat x64
>
> ---
>
> ** Visual Studio 2019 Developer Command Prompt v16.5.1
>   ** Copyright (c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
>   ********************************************************************** ["vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64'
>
> C:\dev\workspace\test3\cmake-build-debug>C:\dev\tools\apps\CLion\ch-0\201.6487.17\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe
>   .. -G "NMake Makefiles"
>   -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.25.28611.0
>   -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual
>   Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.25.28610/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
>   -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual
>   Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.25.28610/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
>   -- works
>   -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
>   -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
>   -- Detecting C compile features
>   -- Detecting C compile features - done
>   -- Configuring done
>   -- Generating done
>   -- Build files have been written to: C:/dev/workspace/test3/cmake-build-debug

if I build the project using nmake the output looks correct (with compiler errors):

> C:\dev\workspace\test3\cmake-build-debug>nmake
>
> Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.25.28611.0
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> Scanning dependencies of target test3 [ 50%] Building C object
>   CMakeFiles/test3.dir/main.c.obj main.c
>   C:\dev\workspace\test3\main.c(6): error C2143: syntax error: missing
>   ';' before 'return' C:\dev\workspace\test3\main.c(7): error C2143:
>   syntax error: missing ';' before '}' NMAKE : fatal error U1077:
>   'C:\PROGRA~2\MIB055~1\2019\PROFES~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1425~1.286\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe'
>   : return code '0x2' Stop. NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe"'
>   : return code '0x2' Stop. NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe"'
>   : return code '0x2' Stop.

however if I try to use cmake to build, it produces empty output:

> C:\dev\workspace\test3\cmake-build-debug>cd ..
>
> C:\dev\workspace\test3>C:\dev\tools\apps\CLion\ch-0\201.6487.17\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe
>   --build C:\dev\workspace\test3\cmake-build-debug --target test3
>
> C:\dev\workspace\test3>

what can be wrong here?

Comment: Please, do not use *blockquote* formatting for logs: this formatting doesn't preserve newlines which makes logs harder to understand. For logs use **code formatting** instead.

Comment: I am unsure, but isn't `--config` option needed for Visual Studio generator? This is **multi-configuration** generator after all.

Comment: there is not Visual Studio generator but NMake Makefiles generator instead. let try to fix a formatting in the post

Comment: Add the option `--config Debug` to your call, i.e. `cmake --build C:\dev\workspace\test3\cmake-build-debug --target test3 --config Debug`

Comment: it did change nothing. the same empty output....

Comment: I've added verbose output and got the reason of the problem - only that host , cmake starts nmake in separate console window so this is why cmake doesn't have any output: nmake produces the output in other window. but I still don't know how to suppress poping up new console window for child process...